# Invalid form POST data - ajax for Authenticated users

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a Drupal form using ajax. When I submit the form I am getting the following being displayed:

[image]

When I check the Drupal log I have the following entry.

[image]

I have Googled the error and found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/invalid-form-post-data-in-ajax-login-form) post but it applies to anonymous users. I am only using this with authenticated users.

Searching for the error in the code returns the `ajax_get_form()` function in `ajax.inc`

```
 $form_state = form_state_defaults();

  $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];

  // Get the form from the cache.
  $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
  if (!$form) {
    // If $form cannot be loaded from the cache, the form_build_id in $_POST
    // must be invalid, which means that someone performed a POST request onto
    // system/ajax without actually viewing the concerned form in the browser.
    // This is likely a hacking attempt as it never happens under normal
    // circumstances, so we just do nothing.
    watchdog('ajax', 'Invalid form POST data.', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    drupal_exit();
  }
```

`$form` is not an object. I am not sure why.

In the `ajax_get_form()` function I am doing ado a `dd()` of `$form_build_id`. This returns me something like `form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE`.

If I perform the following SQL in the database I get a result.

```
select *  from cache_form where cid like '%form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE%';
```

The `cid` in this instance is  `form_state_form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE`.

In form_get_cache() the code is as follows:

```
function form_get_cache($form_build_id, &$form_state) {
  if ($cached = cache_get('form_' . $form_build_id, 'cache_form')) {
     //code missing
  }
}
```

From `cache_get()` we are looking for `form_form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE`but what we have stored in the database is `form_state_form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE`. Of course we do not match so nothing is returned.

I am unsure why this is happening.

My form code is as follows

```
  $form['welcome'] = array(
    '#markup' => //some html markup,
  );


  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Test'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'myform_js',
      'wrapper' => 'message_container',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'event' => 'click',
    ),
  );

  $form['result'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="message_container">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
  );
```

The function `myform_js()` is not being hit as when dd() is added to the top it is not called. I can't see anything obviously wrong with this so not sure if there are any environmental issues that could cause the issue.

I have also tried changing the type of `$form['submit']` to `button`.

It looks that the part that is failing is the call to `cache_set()`. I am unsure as why at the moment.

Comment: Please post your code that is generating your form, so we can try to help you.

Comment: @michaelmol form code has been added.

Comment: global $conf is not where the form would be cached. The cache entry should be created in the cache_form table when you load the page.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong question updated after looking in the correct cache location

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK think I have it.

As `form_form-ymw-BN0Zhp9j2CZf82mZzslbUBiLo8kZbreXhB1y8kE` was not being set I looked at `form_set_cache()`.

```
/**
 * Stores a form in the cache.
 */
function form_set_cache($form_build_id, $form, $form_state) {
  // 6 hours cache life time for forms should be plenty.
  $expire = 21600;

  // Cache form structure.
  if (isset($form)) {
    if ($GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
      $form['#cache_token'] = drupal_get_token();
    }
    cache_set('form_' . $form_build_id, $form, 'cache_form', REQUEST_TIME + $expire);
  }

  // Cache form state.
  if ($data = array_diff_key($form_state, array_flip(form_state_keys_no_cache()))) {
    cache_set('form_state_' . $form_build_id, $data, 'cache_form', REQUEST_TIME + $expire);
  }
}
```

I dug into `cache_set()`

```
function cache_set($cid, $data, $bin = 'cache', $expire = CACHE_PERMANENT) {
  return _cache_get_object($bin)->set($cid, $data, $expire);
}
```

I then looked into `set()`

```
  /**
   * Implements DrupalCacheInterface::set().
   */
  function set($cid, $data, $expire = CACHE_PERMANENT) {
    $fields = array(
      'serialized' => 0,
      'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
      'expire' => $expire,
    );
    if (!is_string($data)) {
      $fields['data'] = serialize($data);
      $fields['serialized'] = 1;
    }
    else {
      $fields['data'] = $data;
      $fields['serialized'] = 0;
    }

    try {
      db_merge($this->bin)
        ->key(array('cid' => $cid))
        ->fields($fields)
        ->execute();
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      // The database may not be available, so we'll ignore cache_set requests.
    }
  }
```

Here an exception is caught and not reported. I added a `dd()` into catch. Looking in drupal_debug.txt

```
[message:protected] => SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

I have now increased the value of `max_allowed_packet` in MySQL. It has fixed things.

With this information I did some more googling and found this [post](http://www.shift8web.ca/blog/2014/11/drupal-problem-an-ajax-http-request-terminated-abnormally/). They have had the same problem that I had.

Comment: So much for empty catch clauses... Fantastic research!

Answer (score 2):

After the "Invalid form POST data" watchdog message, notice that the **ajax_get_form()** function calls **drupal_exit()**.

Your custom module can take advantage of this by hooking into **hook_exit()**... from there you can rebuild the expired/uncached form and attempt to resubmit form using Drupal's ajax_commands framework.

The following is an example of how I resolved this problem for an "AJAX-ified" user-login form.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_exit().
 */
function example_exit($destination = NULL) {
  if (arg(0) == 'system' && arg(1) == 'ajax') {
    $is_user_login_form_submission = isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass']) && isset($_POST['form_build_id']);

    if ($is_user_login_form_submission) {
      watchdog(__FUNCTION__, 'User login AJAX form submission failed. Trying again...', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);

      $form_build_id = $_POST['form_build_id'];
      $form_state = form_state_defaults();
      $form_state['values'] = $_POST; // Important!
      $form = drupal_rebuild_form('user_login', $form_state);
      $form['#build_id_old'] = $form['#build_id']; // Important!

      // Try form submission again after it is rebuilt above
      $commands[] = ajax_command_update_build_id($form);
      $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('form#user-login', 'trigger', array('submit'));

      print ajax_render($commands);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been solved, but I encountered "Invalid form POST data" and the cause was different, so I'll throw it out there for people who come across this.

Basically, my culprit was a cron job that was especially zealous, clearing cache every 5 minutes. The issue wasn't with memory limits or writing to the database, but rather that fairly often the form would get cached, the cache would get cleared, and then attempting to get the form from cache would fail. Switching the cron job to hourly fixed it.